# Fiber of the sheaf of Relative Differentials (Qing Liu)

Tags: commutative-algebra, schemes

In Lemma 6.2.4 of his book, Qing Liu states

> Let  $ X  \to  S  $ be a morphism of finite type  over a locally Noetherian scheme $  S  $.   Fix  $  s \in S $,  $ x \in  X_{s} $  and let $$ d =  \dim_{k(x)} \Omega_{X_{s} /k(s)  , x  }    \otimes _ {  \mathcal{O}_{X_s} }  k(x)  .  $$

My question is, isn't  the module  $  \Omega_{X_{s}/k(s), x }  \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X_s} }  k(x) $ the fiber of $ \Omega_{X/S} $ at $ x \in X  $?

The reason I think that is that first I pullback the sheaf $  \Omega_{X/S} $ along the morphism $ X_{s}  \to  X $ to get $  \Omega_{X_{s} / k(s) } $ and then I pullback along the morphism $ k(x) \to X_{s} $ to get the sheaf/module on $ k(x) $. But since the $ k(x) $ is independent of the space $ X $ or the  fiber $ X_{s} $, I have a composition $ k(x)  \to X_{s}  \to X $, and thus, I am pulling back along this composition.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $\mathscr{O}_{X,s}$?

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: One more question. I know the definition of a fiber of a morphism of schemes. What is a fiber of a sheaf at a point?

Comment: The fiber of a sheaf is the stalk tensored with base field or the pullback along the inclusion morphism of the point into the scheme. If you think of sheaf as a scheme, it's also the usual fiber product.

Comment: Thanks for the comment/definition. Then what is the content of your question? It seems to me that by your definition, you already have an answer to your question. Am I missing something?